# How to get DOM to update automatically - Firebase issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, momentjs, firebase-realtime-database

My homework assignment involves using Firebase and using moment.js to update the time that trains will arrive and how many minutes are left until the next train arrival.
Nearly everything is working except the automatic updating of the train arrival and minutes left.  I had a notion that this would happen automatically by virtue of using Firebase but it's obvious I'm missing something - If I do a page refresh the correct times show.

I could not get the jsfiddle to work with Firebase hence this is missing -

I've also tried `$(document).ready(function()` in various wraps around the entire code and different parts (nearly everything that would make sense - won't enumerate here).

I suspect I'll need to do a `firebase.set()`, `firebase.update()`, or `firebase.push()` and something to those `.vals()`, but before wandering down these various paths and missing my homework deadline I was hoping for a pointer in the right direction, many thanks...

p.s. happy to post HTML/CSS wasn't sure if it was appropriate

---

js code is here:

```
var trainSchedule = new Firebase("https://kittson-trains.firebaseio.com/");
function displayTime() {
 //var time = moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');
 var timeNow = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
 $('#currentTime').html("Current Time Is:  " + timeNow);
 //$('#currentTime').append(time);
 setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);
 };
 displayTime();

//trainSchedule.remove();
$("#trainSubmit").on("click", function(){

    var newTrainName = $("#newTrainNameInp").val().trim();
    var trainDest = $("#trainDestInp").val().trim();        
    var trainFirstTime = $("#trainFirstInp").val().trim();
    var trainFreq = $("#trainFreqInp").val().trim();
    var newTrainData = {
        trainName: newTrainName,
        dest: trainDest,
        freq: trainFreq,
        nxt: trainFirstTime,
    }

    trainSchedule.push(newTrainData);

    $("#newTrainNameInp").val("");
    $("#trainDestInp").val("");
    $("#trainFirstInp").val("");
    $("#trainFreqInp").val("");
    //stay on this page
    return false;   
});

trainSchedule.on("child_added", function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey){

    var newTrainName = childSnapshot.val().trainName;
    var trainDest = childSnapshot.val().dest;
    var trainFirstTime = childSnapshot.val().nxt; 
    var trainFreq = childSnapshot.val().freq;   

    var trainFirstConverted = moment(trainFirstTime,"hh:mm");
    console.log(trainFirstConverted);

    var diffTime = moment().diff(trainFirstConverted, "minutes");
    console.log("DIFFERENCE IN TIME: " + diffTime); 

    var tRemainder = diffTime % trainFreq;
    console.log(tRemainder);

    var minutesTilTrain = trainFreq - tRemainder;
    console.log("MINUTES TILL TRAIN: " + minutesTilTrain);

    var nextTrain = moment().add(minutesTilTrain, "minutes");
    console.log("ARRIVAL TIME: " + moment(nextTrain).format("hh:mm"));

    $("#allTrains > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + newTrainName +
        "</td><td>" + trainDest +
        "</td><td>" + trainFreq +
        "</td><td>" + moment(nextTrain).format("hh:mm") +       
        "</td><td>" + minutesTilTrain + "</td></tr>"); 
});
```

Comment: Anybody with some assistance?  I've tried the `firebase.set()` and `firebase.update()` and have not been able to get these to work (note that firebase is really my firebase database var, trainSchedule.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to start by saying that this is my first time trying to answer a question on here. I'm still pretty new to coding, but hopefully I can be of assistance. I moved your database query into your displayTime function and placed the setInterval in the document.on ready function. The div that stores the table is emptied and updated every second. I'm not sure whether or not this is the best way to continually update the times, but I hope it helps.

```
var trainSchedule = new Firebase("https://kittson-trains.firebaseio.com/");
var displayTime = function() {
  //var time = moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');
  var timeNow = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
  $('#currentTime').html("Current Time Is:  " + timeNow);
  //$('#currentTime').append(time);
  trainSchedule.on("child_added", function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey){

    var newTrainName = childSnapshot.val().trainName;
    var trainDest = childSnapshot.val().dest;
    var trainFirstTime = childSnapshot.val().nxt; 
    var trainFreq = childSnapshot.val().freq;   

    var trainFirstConverted = moment(trainFirstTime,"hh:mm");
    console.log(trainFirstConverted);

    var diffTime = moment().diff(trainFirstConverted, "minutes");
    console.log("DIFFERENCE IN TIME: " + diffTime); 

    var tRemainder = diffTime % trainFreq;
    console.log(tRemainder);

    var minutesTilTrain = trainFreq - tRemainder;
    console.log("MINUTES TILL TRAIN: " + minutesTilTrain);

    var nextTrain = moment().add(minutesTilTrain, "minutes");
    console.log("ARRIVAL TIME: " + moment(nextTrain).format("hh:mm"));

    $('#allTrains > tbody').empty();
    $("#allTrains > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + newTrainName +
        "</td><td>" + trainDest +
        "</td><td>" + trainFreq +
        "</td><td>" + moment(nextTrain).format("hh:mm") +       
        "</td><td>" + minutesTilTrain + "</td></tr>"); 
  });
};

$(document).on('ready', function(){

  setInterval(displayTime, 1000);

  //trainSchedule.remove();
  $("#trainSubmit").on("click", function(){

    var newTrainName = $("#newTrainNameInp").val().trim();
    var trainDest = $("#trainDestInp").val().trim();        
    var trainFirstTime = $("#trainFirstInp").val().trim();
    var trainFreq = $("#trainFreqInp").val().trim();
    var newTrainData = {
        trainName: newTrainName,
        dest: trainDest,
        freq: trainFreq,
        nxt: trainFirstTime,
    }

    trainSchedule.push(newTrainData);

    $("#newTrainNameInp").val("");
    $("#trainDestInp").val("");
    $("#trainFirstInp").val("");
    $("#trainFreqInp").val("");
    //stay on this page
    return false;   
  });

});
```

Comment: just saw your answer - will check it out tomorrow, thanks you for posting

Comment: Let me work this one for a bit - your example updates but somehow clobbers the Firebase data so that there is only one train showing - the others disappear - will post later on what I discover, thanks!